# XML sum of node based on second node

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to add a total of amount per user with matching types. XML sample:

```
<Report_Data>
    <Report_Entry>
        <Name>Mark</Name>
        <Pay>
            <Type>1</Type>
            <Amount>3013</Amount>
        </Pay>
        <Pay>
            <Type>1</Type>
            <Amount>3013</Amount>
        </Pay>
        <Pay>
            <Type>2</Type>
            <Amount>26</Amount>
        </Pay>
    <Report_Entry>
    <Report_Entry>
        <Name>Luke</Name>
        <Pay>
            <Type>1</Type>
            <Amount>2600</Amount>
        </Pay>
        <Pay>
            <Type>1</Type>
            <Amount>3500</Amount>
        </Pay>
        <Pay>
            <Type>3</Type>
            <Amount>1600</Amount>
        </Pay>
    <Report_Entry> 
<Report_Data>
```

**XSL 2.0**

The output should look something like Name/Type/Amount.

Mark16026

Mark20026

Luke16100

Luke31600

I have the formatting fine, however, the loop is only outputting the first type.

Thanks :)

EDIT: Here is the XSLT snippet. This is part of a 3million line xml and 600 line xslt. I purposely watered it down as I am just missing the (right) loop.

```
<xsl:template match="wd:Report_Data">
<xsl:for-each select="wd:Report_Entry">
<xsl:variable name="Worker" select="." />
        <xsl:for-each-group select="//Pay" group-by="wd:Type"> 
            <xsl:variable name="Money" select="." />
            <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(Type, ' ')">
                <xsl:if test="(.!='0')"> 
  <xsl:call-template name="FormatFixedWidthString">
            <xsl:with-param name="size">4</xsl:with-param>
            <xsl:with-param name="stringValue">
                <xsl:value-of select="$Worker/Name"/>
            </xsl:with-param>
            <xsl:with-param name="justify">right</xsl:with-param>
            <xsl:with-param name="fill">
                <xsl:text></xsl:text>
            </xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:call-template>
 <xsl:call-template name="FormatFixedWidthString">
            <xsl:with-param name="size">1</xsl:with-param>
            <xsl:with-param name="stringValue">
                <xsl:value-of select="$Money/Type"/>
            </xsl:with-param>
            <xsl:with-param name="justify">right</xsl:with-param>
            <xsl:with-param name="fill">
                <xsl:text></xsl:text>
            </xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:call-template>
 <xsl:call-template name="FormatFixedWidthString">
            <xsl:with-param name="size">4</xsl:with-param>
            <xsl:with-param name="stringValue">
                <xsl:value-of select="$Money/Value"/>
            </xsl:with-param>
            <xsl:with-param name="justify">right</xsl:with-param>
            <xsl:with-param name="fill">
                <xsl:text>0</xsl:text>
            </xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use

```
<xsl:template match="Report_Entry">
  <xsl:for-each-group select="Pay" group-by="Type">
    <xsl:value-of select="../Name, current-grouping-key(), sum(current-group()/Amount)"/>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>
```

then you should get the sums you want.

In the code you posted now I think you need to change

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="//Pay" group-by="wd:Type">
```

to

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="Pay" group-by="wd:Type">
```

or

```
<xsl:for-each-group select=".//Pay" group-by="wd:Type">
```

to process only the `Pay` elements inside of the `Report_Entry`.

And if you want to compute a sum then you need to use

```
<xsl:with-param name="stringValue" select="sum(current-group()/Value)"/>
```

instead of

```
        <xsl:with-param name="stringValue">
            <xsl:value-of select="$Money/Value"/>
        </xsl:with-param>
```

Comment: Hm... This worked on my "Watered down" version but on the real data I'm getting an **XPTY0004: Required item type of first argument of string-length() is xs:string; supplied value has item type xs:double** error

Comment: Well you don't show us any code using the `string-length` function, assuming the variable name `stringValue` indicates that the parameter needs to be of type `xs:string` you can try `<xsl:with-param name="stringValue" select="string(sum(current-group()/Value))"/>`.